# How to get the ID of linked table in JPA repository

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data-jpa, entity-relationship

I have the following code in which I want to get the id of rider, But I have no idea how to do this , Actually rider is the type of User which is linked to `RiderLocation` table , When I change the type of rider to User then I cant send the id in parameter of URL like this

http://localhost:3000/api/riderLocations/search/findByRider?rider_id=3

Code is below

**RiderLocation.java**

```
@Entity
public class RiderLocation implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;

        @ManyToOne
        private User rider;

        private Double latitude;
        private Double longitude;

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public User getRider() {
            return rider;
        }
        public void setRider(User rider) {
            this.rider = rider;
        }
        public Double getLatitude() {
            return latitude;
        }

        public void setLatitude(Double latitude) {
            this.latitude = latitude;
        }

        public Double getLongitude() {
            return longitude;
        }
      public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
            this.longitude = longitude;
        }
    }
```

**RiderLocationRepository**

```
public interface RiderLocationRepository extends JpaRepository<RiderLocation, Long>{

    @Query("select r.latitude,r.longitude from RiderLocation r ")
    ArrayList<Object[]>   findAllRidersLocation();
    RiderLocation findByRider(@Param("rider_id") Long rider);

}
```

Comment: is id also part of Rider object?

Comment: 'id' is the part of RiderLOcation id @sAm

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved now 
the only mistake is I wrote

`findByRider(@Param("rider_id") Long rider);`

instead of :

`findByRiderId(@Param("rider_id") Long rider);`